# Program working Fine in one compiler but showing error in codechef

Tags: c

I am new to programming and was doing the beginner level problems at codechef. [Problem Code: FLOW006]

The question is as follows:

> You're given an integer N. Write a program to calculate the sum of all
> the digits of N.
>
> Input The first line contains an integer T, the total number of
> testcases. Then follow T lines, each line contains an integer N.
>
> Output For each test case, calculate the sum of digits of N, and
> display it in a new line.
>
> Constraints: 1 ≤ T ≤ 1000, 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000000, Example: Input 3  12345 31203
> 2123 Output: 15 9 8

Here's the program i wrote:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int y = 1, T, N, x = 0, d, e, f, g, c;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    if (T <= 1000 && T >= 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < T; x++) {
            c = pow(10, 1);
            scanf("%d", &N);
            if (N <= 1000000 && N >= 1) {
                e = 0;
                for (y = 0; c < N; y++) {
                    c = pow(10, y + 1);
                    f = N % c;
                    g = pow(10, y);
                    d = f / g;
                    e = e + d;
                }
                printf("%d\n", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this is working in my compiler but is showing wrong answer when i submit it at codechef.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please tell your editor to properly indent your code. This is **very** hard to read, and that means it's very easy to hide a small mistake in there. Code formatting is important to the human reader, and especially you, the human coder!

Comment: could you please elaborate what I should do?

Comment: If you must use `pow` you could try `g = (int)round(pow(10, y));`

Comment: also, `pow` is a `double` floating point function and *should really not be used for integer math`; for large integers, the numbers represenatble by floating point numbers and integers are not the same.

Comment: @AseemMittal I don't know what editor you used to write this code. But if it's a useful editor, it has a button to "format code". Do that! You can also go to https://gcc.godbolt.org/ and paste your code there, right click, and "Format Document", and copy paste the result back here.

Comment: Read the problem limits more carefully. What will the program do when `T == 1000` or when `N == 1000000`? Also, consider separating the answer output for each test case with a newline. If the answers are say `1`, `2` and `3` your program outputs `123`.

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: @WeatherVane what is the difference between 'pow' and '(int)round(pow(10,y))'?

Comment: Well if `pow(10,3)` should return 999.9999999 (it might) then `g` will be 999, not 1000.

Comment: Why are you even testing the range of `T` and `N`? These are the problem's contraints: the point is that the input is *guaranteed* to be in these limits, to help you design the program.

Comment: how sum of dogits of 3 can be 15?

Comment: @0___________ could you please tell what you want to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your program and it's really wrong. There is a '{' wrong, so it performs different than you imagine. It also doesn't work for numbers with one digit, like 1, 2, 3.

Also, your program doesn't skip the lines between the answers, that's probably a problem too.

Try to find the errors for yourself; if you tried and could not come up with the solution, I will leave what I think is the correct one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    int y=1,T,N,x=0,d,e,f,g,c;
    scanf ("%d",&T);
    if (T<1000){
        for (x=0;x<T;x++)
        {
            c=0;
            scanf ("%d",&N);
            e=0;
            for (y=0;c<N;y++)
                if (N<1000000)
                {
                    c=pow(10,y+1);
                    f=N%c;
                    g=pow(10,y);
                    d=f/g;
                    e=e+d;
                }
            printf ("%d\n",e);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the one i have uploaded here is actually working correctly on larger numbers. I agree it is showing incorrect result on single digit values. will work on it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use float numbers when you deal with integers.

Function summing the digits of the number is very simple without any floats, power operations, just using the division and modulus. This function handles also negative numbers.

```
int sumDigits(int x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(x)
    {
        sum += abs(x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And the test program:

```
int main(void)
{
    int T, N;
    
    if(scanf("%d", &T) != 1) { /* handle error */ }
    if(T >= 1 && T <= 1000)
    {
        while(T--)
        {
            if(scanf("%d", &N) != 1) { /* handle error */ }
            if(N > 0 && N <= 100000)
            {
                printf("The sum of digits of %d is %d\n", N, sumDigits(N));
            }
            else
            {
                /* handle wrong input */ 
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
         /* handle wrong input */ 
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KfqTPdfcx

and the result:

```
The sum of digits of 12345 is 15
The sum of digits of 31203 is 9
The sum of digits of 2123 is 8
```

Comment: but i am not using any floating values, I have defined all variables in integer. Also, why have you put the scanf statement in if operator? Lastly, where exactly did my code go wrong?

Comment: `pow` is float function. So you mix `double` result of this function with integers.

Comment: Hmmm didn't know that. Also, why did you write the scanf statement in if operator?

Comment: Because it is the correct way of doing it. scanf returns the number of successful conversions, so if it is not `1` in this case it means that something has gone wrong and you need to handle the error

Comment: Aside: these problems don't have any way to handle input error, no recovery is possible and there is no point checking. The input is guaranteed to conform to the problem description. This in one reason why they make such a bad teaching resource - essential checks which you would make in serious code can be simply skipped. Likewise it is pointless checking the number of test cases or the range of input. There *are* `<= 1000` test cases and the maximum data value *is* `<= 1000000`. The question says so: they are stated so that you know what array sizes, integer types, and so on to use.

Comment: No, I am saying that error checking the input for this problem does not help to solve it in the slightest. If the input is incorrect, then the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: Then something has to be done - for example, program termination.

Comment: Sorry, I explicity stated "essential checks which you would make in serious code." In practice, these types of problems usually have a time limit constraint, and checking something that is futile to check, just wastes execution time. It doesn't matter whether the program is terminated or not.

Comment: @WeatherVane for beginners asking questions here every code is serious. They should learn the correct habits. One is : "if something might go wrong - write some error handling". I know  it is boring, time consuming and very often 70% of code only handles errors.

Comment: It is valuable advice, but it doesn't answer the question. Not only is it unnecessary for these challenges, but impedes finding a solution. They *don't* have to follow your good advice, *in this situation*. In real code, yes, but to solve this problem, no.

Comment: @WeatherVane you have probably not noticed but my answer is focused on the problem, not on error handling. Do you have any comments regarding the solution?

Comment: No, my take on code challenges is that if you can't solve them, move on to another, for the same reason as above: they are a poor learning resource. The whole idea is that the coder does solve it themself. That's not to say that people shouldn't ask about a particular aspect of coding, or an algorithm though.

Comment: @0___________ isn't scanf used to take the value of a variable from the user? Also, what exactly do you mean by the statement "scanf returns the number of successful conversions"?